# Run fish script in background?

Tags: fish

I'd like to always run a fish script in the background even if the user doesn't specify that.

In bash, this can be done by surrounding the script with `(` at the start and `) &` at the end.

Is there anyway for a fish script to run itself in the background?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain a bit more clearly. When should the script be launched? At boot time? After the user logs in? Every time a terminal is opened? What user should run the script? Also, all you need to send a command to the background is `command &`, the `$(command) &` syntax you describe is something else (and makes little sense).

Comment: If the script is `foo.fish`, then I intended for the script to run in the background when the user executes `./foo.fish`. Surrounding multiple lines with `()` runs them in a subshell and `&` runs them in the background. Anyway, feel free to ignore this question as I've found out that it's not possible: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/238

Comment: Well, yes, you can use a subshell, it's just not needed (and sorry, I thought you were using command substitution there). Anyway, you can do this in fish as well, just run `./foo.fish &`. The post you linked to is about sending *functions* to the background. We might be able to help you but you need to give us a specific example.

Comment: The goal is to run the script in the background even if the user doesn't run `./foo.fish &`. So even if the user runs `./foo.fish`, the script should run in the background. The reason is because the script is invoked from an openvpn config file with the line `ipchange foo.fish` which doesn't support any arguments and cannot use `&`.

Comment: Ah, OK, now I get it. Please [edit] your question and add these details though. Would using two scripts be acceptable? One that actually does the work (`foo.fish`) and one, `bar.sh`, that calls it as a background process: `foo.fish &`. You then have your user run `bar.sh` instead of `foo.fish`.

Comment: Job control proper is at the level of the calling shell. Would you like the script to continue running while returning a shell prompt to the caller?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

fish does not fork to execute subshells, so it is not yet possible to run fish script in the background - see https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/563

A hackish workaround is to invoke fish again, like so:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/fish
fish -c 'sleep 5 ; echo done' &
```